# Getter function for public variables

Tags: solidity, state-variable

Many token contracts have unrestricted getter functions for state variables, which seems redundant (eg, see OpenZepplin's [ERC20 contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)). For example, a contract could have it this way:

```
uint private _totalSupply;

function totalSupply() view public returns (uint) {
return _totalSupply
}
```

or this way:

```
uint public totalSupply;
```

Web3.js and solidity would use the exact same syntax--totalSupply--to retrieve the variable "totalSupply."  As the former is more common, but also more verbose, I presume I am missing some way in which a getter function dominates querying a contract directly. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You're missing the fact that in the first case, only this contract can change the value of the `totalSupply` variable, whereas in the second case, every inheriting contract can also change the value of the `totalSupply` variable. That is why OZ have moved from `public` variables on their v1 to `private` variables on their v2. Off-chain-wise (e.g., web3.js), both paradigms are identical of course.

Comment: I don't see it. The mutability of totalsupply is not affected by whether it is private or public.

Comment: An inheriting contract can change it if it's public, but not if it's private, what exactly don't you see here???

Comment: I was thinking purely about a single contract, not inheritance. So, I see it now from that perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the fact that in the first case, only this contract can change the value of the `totalSupply` private variable, whereas in the second case, every inheriting contract can also change the value of the `totalSupply` public variable.

BTW, that is why OpenZepplin moved from public variables to private variables when they released v2.

Off-chain-wise (e.g., web3.js), both paradigms are identical of course, because the Solidity compiler auto-generates a public function for every public state-variable in the contract.

Comment: The second case could also be `uint internal totalSupply;` and the same would hold true for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of better reusability. You can't override generated getter functions in possible child contracts but you can if the function is explicitly written out (like in your first example). Also I would claim it's a matter of better readability: many outside people don't know about generated getter functions so it's difficult for them to understand the code with implicit getter functions.